# Android Flash Light widget code crashing

Tags: java, android, flash, widget

could someone explain me why my code is crashing at..

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters(); //crashing line
```

the code is

```
package it.elec29a.ultra.flashlight;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private Camera camera=null;
  @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        // if device support camera?
        if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return;
        }
if(camera!=null) camera=Camera.open();


    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("In Widget ",""+widgetId);



        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonwidget, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters(); //crashing line
    if(true) return; //for debug exit

    String flashMode = p.getFlashMode();
    if(flashMode == null) {
     //DO something, if it has no value
    } else if(flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF)) {
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(p);
    } else if(flashMode.equals(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(p);
    }

  }
}
```

Could someone help me to fix this problem ... thx

Comment: By the way, your `camera` variable might as well be `null` when you call `getParameters()` as you haven't enclosed that call within the check for `null` some lines above.

Comment: ah ok it is now working .. did change the line

Comment: I added some more details in the answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two visible issues in your code.

Your line:

```
if(camera!=null) camera=Camera.open();
```

... initializes your `Camera` object if it's not `null` (which sounds weird - might never be initialized).

However all the code below, including:

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
```

... does **not** depend on the fact that `camera != null`, so it might be referencing a `null` pointer.

Hence you might very well throw a `NullPointerException` (I say "might" because you haven't posted the stack trace).

I would change your code as such:

```
// removed if(camera!=null) 
camera = Camera.open();

// checking "camera" is not null
if (camera != null) { // using curly brackets, comes very handy sometimes :D
    // ... the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: thx new problem and new code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302932/android-flash-widget-service-intent-stop-app-in-app